# Validate Not Triggered When Saving (Updating) Existing Model

Tags: javascript, web-applications, backbone.js

I'd appreciate help in understanding why the validate method is NOT triggered when saving (i.e. updating) an existing model in backbone.js version 1.0.0. Following is simplified pseudo-code; the "new" (model) place is validated, but the "existing" (model) place is not validated on save.

```
if (id) {

 // options contains places collection

 place = this.options.places.get(id);

 place.on('invalid', function(m,e) {...});

 place.save({...}, {wait: true, error: ..., success: ...})

} else {

 place = new App.Place()

 place.on('invalid', function(m,e) {...});

 place.save({...}, {wait: true, error: ..., success: ...})

}
```

Thanks.

-Ari

Comment: Seeing Backbone's Model's save method code, there are 2 ways not to have the validate method run. First is not having a validate method (you most certainly have one...). Second is not having the 'wait' flag set to true. Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'd suggest you just step into the code using the debugger and see why it's skipping the call to `validate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing validation by passing `{ validate: true }`:

```
place.save({...}, {wait: true, error: ..., success: ..., validate: true });
```